# VMWare Server with multiple processors

Tags: vmware-server

I have a new linux machine with two Core Duo CPUs. However, VMWare Server only recognizes one. In the host summary it shows: Processors: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU 750 @ 2.67GHz 1 CPU x 2 Cores

On another machine, it shows: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q6700 @ 2.66GHz 1 CPU x 4 Cores

This machine also has two CPUs.

Why is VMWare not seeing all the CPUs?

Answer (score 4):

No you don't, none of those chips are multi-processor capable.

Can you tell us what the machine actually has rather than what linux says it has, then we can help.